# Jquery Each Input Within DIV (Has A Table)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, foreach

Im currently trying to get all input elements from a DIV.

```
$("[required]").each(function() {

});
```

I have this code which returns every element with a `required` attribute.

I know within the function of that `each()` I can use each item like:

```
$(this)
```

So I get the div ID's shown below, and try to get all the inputs from it via:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
console.log("### " + id);
console.log($("#" + id + " > :input").length);
```

Which returns 0 when I have 4 in put elements within that DIV (also theres a table in the div).

What I would ideally like to do is for each input element within my div, print its ID.

UPDATED

```
<div id="contactAddress" required="true">

 <td>Addres line 1:</td>
 <td colspan="2">
 <input type="text"/>
 </td>
 <td>Addres line 2:</td>
 <td colspan="2">
 <input type="text" />
 </td>
 </tr>
</div>

console.log($(this).html());
```

Shows nothign but if i add anythign outsire the  or  like below...

```
 <div id="contactAddress" required="true">
 <input type="text" />
```

And run  `console.log($(this).html());` It shows it put not the table?

Any ideas im using Jquery Mobile

Comment: do you mena something like this
$("#parent-id input[type=text]").each(function(){     });  ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This below will find all inputs inside the div element. It will then leave a log of the id of this element.

```
$("div > input").each(function() {
  console.log( $(this).attr("id") );
});
```

if you need the div id containing the inputs you could use `.parent()`

```
$("input").each(function() {
  console.log( $(this).parent().attr("id") );
});
```

Comment: Yes but for either the div ID or the this (being the div element)

Comment: $(this) refers to each input as it goes through each. You need the id of the div?

Comment: var id = $(element).attr('id');
$("#" + id + " > input")